# Advantage of using spring view resolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

What is the advantage of using Spring view resolver.

I am using ajax calls to call the web service without view resolver. Whether changing the configuration using view resolver provides benefits.

More specifically does html view resolver provides anything related to security or session management .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not related to security or session management. In your case, i.e. when you are using `@RestController` or `@Controller`+`@ResponseBody` to send the response directly, view resolvers wouldn't be needed. They are needed only when you want your controller methods to forward to a view.

Comment: How can I use security in this ajax calls. Will a spring security login using basic http forn is enough.

Comment: Security could be similar whether it's AJAX or not. I use form based security over https with remember-me if the user opts to.